# Why use Observable in Angular instead of object reference

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with a kind of gamefication and every task the user completes I add a string to an array *achievements*. I was using Observables in my Gamefication service to update the *achievements* array so the UI would update as well, changing the color of some "achievements badges"
The thing is.
I realized that if I simply assign an array in my component consuming my service with the reference of the array in the service like this:

gamefication.page.ts

```
export class GameficationPage implements OnInit {
  
  gameficationCards: GameCard[];

  constructor(private gameficationService: GameficationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameficationCards = this.gameficationService.getAvailableCards();
  }

}
```

And the service like this:
gamefication.service.ts

```
gameficationCards: string[] = [
'acheivement1',
'achievement2',
...
]
getAvailableCards() {
    return this.gameficationCards;
  }
```

Whenever I update the gameficationCards array in the service, my page, consuming the gamefication service , and my UI updates as well.
I'd like to know why does it work and why should I use an observable for changing values if I can just simply update my array and it will reflect in the UI.

Thank you.

Comment: This code only updates the component when it’s created for the first time, not when achievements are updated after the component is created. If u use observables, you can update ui for existing components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [sample Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lhqcp8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In your post you have mentioned

> Whenever I update the gameficationCards array in the service, my page, consuming the gamefication service

Very true, as long as angular detects a change it will update the UI, so to answer the question why does this work? Simply there was a change in the data and hence need to trigger change detection and update the data

> Angular can detect when component data changes, and then automatically re-render the view to reflect that change

Now check the demo I have posted above, I have reproduced your issue with a simple change, I have added

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Now the difference is seen... Using function no longer works and the UI is not updated even if the data is updated! So to answer your question

> why should I use an observable for changing values if I can just simply update my array and it will reflect in the UI.

then it depends, If you plan on improving the performance of your application using `OnPush` strategy of change detection, then the better option will be to implement the use of `Observable`

Comment: Thank you very very much ! You've clarified, so using a State Manager is the proper way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your example your app behave in a synchronous way, which does **not** reflect a real world app.
In fact, in your case, you firstly make sure that the *gameficationCards* array is not empty (by filling it with values), then you try to get its contents in a synchronous workflow.

Two main problems here:

1. Your array here is filled in client side (which is not, in most cases, a proper way to do so )
2. Did you think about the case when these achievements would be retrieved from a backend service ? how would you ensure that your array contains values to make your `this.gameficationService.getAvailableCards()` ?

Answering the second question will lead you to *Observables*

---

***Hint* : javascript's asynchronous behavior.**

Comment: Awesome ! So the proper way is to always fill the array and perform operations like filtering etc, in the backend and then fetching it in an asynchronous way using observables. Right? I would do something like:
this.http.get<SomeDTOWithAnArrayProperty>(...) , is there any material talking about it ? The proper way to implement these kind of operations, or some design pattern that assures it ?

Comment: @NikolasL. , Exactly ! Yes IMO, it is cleaner and that's how it works eventually. Client sides are meant to consume data more than computing them (unless it is required)

Comment: @NikolasL., I think internet is full of such tutos, start by seeing what's REST api..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about using observables vs. updating the array which is data bound: the main advantage of using an observable is the fact that you can have it in a service and subscribe to it from different components.

That way, whenever your array changes, you can send it to the observable, and all of its subscribers will be notified of the change and updated.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. But if I just simply pass the reference, all other services will update as well, right? Because even if I don't use observable, whenever I change a property directly in my array in the service, it seems to be already bound. Is it correct to do this way?